# how to create a link to open app?

Tags: links

I want to add a button to my WordPress website that, when clicked on a mobile device, will open a specific app installed on the device. For example, I want to create a "Open {app_name}" button that will open the app on the user's mobile device (with a predefined location-optional). How can I achieve this functionality? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can have different cases like whatsapp provide a custom  so you need only link to this
https://faq.whatsapp.com/425247423114725/?cms_platform=iphone&helpref=platform_switcher

or calling a app direct instagram://user?username={USERNAME} as link

Your question has been answered here already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787496/opening-instagram-app-on-mobile-and-url-on-desktop